# Set a chart control's X axis to a 10 minute timeline

Tags: c#

I am using a line chart to display motion detection levels on a video.

I need to get the X Axis to display a timeline. For example, if the media player control returns 600 seconds as the length of video, then the X Axis should display from 00:00 to 10:00 along the buttom, with perhaps 10 intervals in total.

So far, I have got this:

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
```

Which isn't much.  I have searched online but the examples that I have found seem to be aimed at a real life date range,and not a simple, 0 to 10 minute range.

How can I get a simple 10 minute time line for the x axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use actual DateTime values in your Chart, here is how to set it up:

```
Series s = chart1.Series[0];
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;

s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
s.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;

DateTime dt0 = DateTime.MinValue;  // any date will do, just know which you use!
ax.Minimum = dt0.AddSeconds(0).ToOADate();
ax.Maximum = dt0.AddSeconds(600).ToOADate();
ax.Interval = 10;
ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
ax.MajorGrid.Interval = 15;
ax.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
ax.MinorGrid.Interval = 5;
ax.MinorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
ax.LabelStyle.Interval = 60;
ax.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
ax.LabelStyle.Format = "mm:ss";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    s.Points.AddXY(dt0.AddSeconds(rnd.Next(30) + 40 * i).ToOADate(), i);
}
```

here is the result:

[image]

You could instead keep everything in the number domain; but then you can't format the x-axis labels as times nor use the x-values directly in calculating time values, which may or may not be a problem:

```
s.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

ax.Minimum = 0;
ax.Maximum = 600;
ax.Interval = 10;
ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
ax.MajorGrid.Interval = 15;
ax.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
ax.MinorGrid.Interval = 5;
ax.MinorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
ax.LabelStyle.Interval = 60;
ax.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time writing this up. Although I'm getting overflow errors. I should have said that the X axis on the graph is generated frame by frame. So there are around 4000 frames in a 10 minute video. So I guess this is where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Yes, probably. Note how I s create the time values for the DataPoints by adding them to a start time. How do you add the DataPoints

Comment: My code loops through every frame of a video and produces a motion value for every frame. I add this to the chart simply with this: `chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(valueToAdd);`

Comment: Many thanks for your help with this. I think I may keep it to frame numbers for now and look into this further in the future.

Comment: Well, this (ie using AddY)  means that you don't actually set x-values; this is usually not a good idea, esp. if you want to control the details of the axis display etc.. So do consider using the AddXY method.  You can either use a counter i or the current Point.Count and add them as the appropriate time values to a start time. to add a frame every 25ms use this: `...Points.AddXY( dt0.AddMilliseconds(i * 25),..);`