# create multiple series line chart in winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql, charts

Using this below sql stored procedure I want to create line chart with 3 line in my winforms app, but during execution I am getting this below error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

In the line:

```
 Chrtline.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(Datetable, Turningtable);
```

kindly help me how to solve this, and what I am doing wrong:

My sql stored procedure:

```
@fromDate Date,
 @toDate Date
 as
 SELECT [Date],
 isnull([Milling],0)as [Milling],
 isnull([Turning],0) as [Turning],
 isnull([EDM],0) as [EDM] FROM (
   SELECT
     [Date],
     Department,
     Count(Action_Status) as Status
   FROM Semicon_NPD
   Where (Date between  @fromDate  and  @toDate) and (Action_Status = 'Pending')
    group by Department,[Date]
 ) StatusCount
 PIVOT (
   SUM([Status])
   FOR [Department]
   IN (
     [Milling],
     [Turning],
     [EDM]
   )
 )
  AS PivotTable
```

my code for populating chart:

```
private void statusline()
         {
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("statusline", con);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", dtfrom.Value);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", dtto.Value);
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             con.Open();
             SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 Datetable.Add(dr.GetDateTime(0));
                 Millingcount.Add(dr.GetInt32(1));
                 Turningtable.Add(dr.GetInt32(2));
                 EDMtable.Add(dr.GetInt32(3));
    
             }
             Chrtline.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(Datetable, Millingcount);
             Chrtline.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(Datetable, Turningtable);
             Chrtline.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(Datetable, EDMtable);
             dr.Close();
             con.Close();
         }
```

example result set(sql result):
[image]

Comment: Do you actually have 3 Series? You need to add at least 2 in code! - Btw: The title of the post seems to be quite misleading: You don't really want multiple y-axes but multiple Series, right?

Comment: @TaW yes i am sorry it's just multiple series..sorry for the mistake

Comment: OK. __But did you create all 3 Series??__ When you drop a Chart in the designer __one__ series is added by default. You can any more either in the designer or in code..

Comment: @TaW thank you so much for your response ..that what i was missing !! ..could you please help me one more issue ..the X-axis is showing dates as "44629" how to change this to "13-02"(ddd-mm)??

Comment: If you have added a valid date you should thell the Axis that its `XValueType` id DateTime. Then you can set the `yourXAxis.LabelStyle.Format` to maybe "ddd-MM"  (Note that m is minute and M is month!)

Comment: @TaW thank you ..could you provide me a link which has a working example?

Comment: I'm sure with a few trails you'll manage to get what you want. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816226/set-a-chart-controls-x-axis-to-a-10-minute-timeline/39816461#39816461) is one exmaple but it will not necessarily be what you need..